# How to create HTML emails to prevent users accidentally selecting additional spaces when copy pasting

Tags: html, html-email, copy-paste

I have an email that goes out with a string that needs to be once-off copy pasted.

The problem I have is that a lot of users don't really pay attention to how they are copying from within outlook and seem to always copy an extra space at the end of it.

I see how they can do it, I always have to backtrack to copy it properly. The initial selection looks like

[image: Overselect]

and after i backtrack and be more accurate it looks like

[image: correct select]

the problem I have is that a not insignificant amount of people are copying the space and then having problems.

Here's the way I'm handling that area of the html. Is there something that's triggering this that i can swap out to improve things.

```
<p style="margin-top: 0;">
 <span style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:#222222; line-height: 1.6;"> 
  <span style="color: #222;">We have recently upgraded the security for accounts.</span>
  <br><br> To complete the account upgrade process, you will need to set up a new password. Below, you will find a temporary password that you can use to log in and create a new, stronger password of your choice. 
  <br><br> 
  <b>Temporary Password: 
   <span style="font-size: 22px; margin-left: 5px; border:1px solid #ccc; color: #222222; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 5px;">{####}</span>
  </b> 
 </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Why is this is a problem? If this "code" is used/being pasted a textfield (to verify something) you can just `trim` the pasted content and the problem is solved. (Sidenote: just make sure to not add any leading/trailing spaces to the generated temp password though)

Comment: its generated through a 3rd party provider, I don't think it will generate one with a space, but, it's technically not invalid to have a trailing space.

Comment: The only time you will end up with trailing space is if the user double clicks for a selection. If its selected in a normal way then there will not be an issue. Maybe update the wording coz we cant change user behaviour in an email.

Answer (score 0):

You could design it as a table, and so have the password in a cell by itself.

Something like:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;>Temporary Password:</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px 10px;">{####}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```